# How to set the override the redis host name for different environments in Azure web role project?

Tags: azure, redis, web-config

Azure redis cache:

I am implementing redis cache for maintaining the session state for our site. Our site is a Azure web role project and all the configurations are in the *.cscfg files for different environments. I am wondering how I can set the host to different values for different environments. For example to sample-int.redis.cache.windows.net, sample-test.redis.cache.windows.net, sample.redis.cache.windows.net and be able to use other attributes from the web.config file:

```
    <sessionState timeout="5760" mode="Custom" customProvider="MySessionStateStore">
  <providers>
  <add name="MySessionStateStore" type="Microsoft.Web.Redis.RedisSessionStateProvider" host="sample-int.redis.cache.windows.net" accessKey="r7gdUggfxIRJLmz5wSq1vacnjAawCjjIIXZCaN2dsWM=" ssl="true" />
  </providers>
</sessionState>
```

Answer (score 0):

I put my redis configuration in the web.config and per environment transformation files.  I don't put much application settings data in the .cscfg files.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways of providing values for session state config parameter.

1) Directly in web.config
2) Using AppSettings

I think what you are trying to do is provide it at run time somehow, there is no way to do that.